# If I only send PostgreSQL WAL(write ahead log) files from primary server to another server, PITR will work?

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

my database size is 100 GB and it takes time to send this big size dump to another server. I am doing WAL log archiving(incremental backup) of the primary database right now. Is it possible if only send the updated WAL files to the secondary server and the secondary server will contain as same data as the primary?

Comment: You still have to initialize the standby with a base backup.

Comment: at the initial stage, I took a basebackup of the primary server cluster and initialized the secondary server with the basebackup files. after that, if I 'only' send the updated WAL files of the primary server to the secondary, then both servers will be the same?

Comment: Right, that's the idea of streaming replication.

Comment: yes it works in recovery mode